# Finding "Super Voice Recorder" files on computer after it was created on my Android 8

Tags: internal-storage, windows, files

I have two recording apps on my Samsung Galaxy S8. "Super Voice recorder" which I use to tape meetings to create meeting notes and "Call Recorder" that records phone conversations.

When I sync to my Windows computer, I see all of my phone call conversations (from Call Recorder) as MP3 and it is in the audio file, but I do not see any of my Super Voice Recorder files. The folder is completely empty but the app on my phone tells me I have 5 files.

Where is it stored outside the application?

Comment: Check in the root folder - some apps create a separate folder there to store information

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using [Super Voice Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.meihillman.audiorecorder) from [MeiHillMan](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=MeiHillMan).

He has mentioned the storage location of your files in

- [Play Store Page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.meihillman.audiorecorder)

  > Audio recording files are stored into “**AllVoiceRecords**” in your SD card root folder. In addition to using the built-in player, you can use your device’s file browser or a USB PC connection to view, copy or share the files in the directory.
- **Android Application**

  > All recording files are placed under the directory "AllVoiceRecords" (this directory is at the root of SD Card). Apart from viewing or playing in this application, you can also manually view or copy those records using a file browser, or transfer them to your PC through USB connection.

  <sup>[Original screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9gzGl.png)</sup>

On Windows, if you can't see your files from Explorer, and you're familiar with ADB, open CMD shell and try this command:

```
adb pull /sdcard/AllVoiceRecords %userprofile%\desktop
```

You'll find a folder called **AllVoiceRecords** on your desktop.

Otherwise, if you want to view your files via Windows Explorer, try [media.Re.Scan](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.house.noranuko.mediarescanner) application to scan your MTP media storage and update its information.